# Build LTS dependencies only with no stack.yaml

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I would like to implement a multistage Dockerfile with three stages:

1. pull `fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12` and build all LTS dependencies
2. copy `stack.yaml` and `package.yml` and build all extra-deps
3. copy `.` and build the actual project

So far I managed to separate 2 and 3, but 1 and 2 are still executed together, which means that every single time either `stack.yaml` or `package.yaml` change, the entire LTS needs to be recompiled. This takes roughly 20 minutes every time, whereas in local dev (without Docker), when I modify `stack.yaml` or `package.yaml`, only the "new stuff" gets compiled and it's usually very quick.

Doing this "LTS-only" first compilation in a separate Docker stage would allow Docker to cache the results and avoid recompiling everything all the time.

When I try to `stack build --dependencies-only` with no YAML files, Stack complains that this folder is not a Stack project directory.

Is it possible to pre-compile only the LTS with no `yaml` file and, thereafter, compile the project based on `stack.yaml`?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that my question, as it is phrased, doesn't make sense.

Stack doesn't "compile the entire LTS". It compiles only the modules that the project's dependencies need. Therefore, it can't do anything without a `stack.yaml` and a `package.yaml` (or `project.cabal`).

A workaround is to use a `long-term` subfolder with a `stack.yaml` and a `package.yaml` files listing the dependencies that will change very rarely (say `aeson`, `text`, `bytestring`...).

```markdown
project-dir/
    long-term/
        stack.yaml
        package.yaml
    stack.yaml
    package.yaml
```

Then in the first stage of the Dockerfile:

```markdown
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12 as dependencies

# ...

COPY ./long-term/stack.yaml ./long-term/package.yaml ./
RUN stack build --test --no-run-tests --dependencies-only

COPY ./stack.yaml ./package.yaml ./stack.yaml.lock ./
RUN stack build --test --no-run-tests --dependencies-only
```

As long as these two long-term files aren't touched, Docker will happily reuse the cached results.

And now, making a one-line change into the "actual" `stack.yaml` or `package.yaml` doesn't need to recompile the whole world.

--

Loose inspiration taken from: https://gist.github.com/and-pete/e8fd63d51121c61d25461bcc2b3fe743